# ngMaterial flex layout not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flexbox

I seem to be unable to get ngMaterial to layout as a row a simple hello world app. I dont see any errors in the console, is it obvious what I am doing incorrect? I would expect the below to layout blah, blag horizontally.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <!-- AngularJS-ngMaterial-->
      <link src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.0-rc4/angular-material.css' />
      <link src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.0-rc4/angular-material.layouts.css' />
      <!-- /AngularJS-ngMaterial-->
  
  </head>
  <body ng-app='myApp' layout='column'>
      <md-toolbar>
        <h1>Angular Material - Starter</h1>
      </md-toolbar>
      
      <div layout='row'>
        <div flex>
          blag
        </div>
        <div flex>
          blah
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <!-- AngularJS-->
      <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.js'></script>
      <!-- /AngularJS-->
  
      <!-- AngularJS-ngAria-->
      <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular-aria.js'></script>
      <!-- /AngularJS-ngAria-->
  
      <!-- AngularJS-ngAnimate-->
      <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular-animate.js'></script>
      <!-- /AngularJS-ngAnimate-->
  
      <!-- AngularJS-ngMaterial-->
      <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.0-rc4/angular-material.js'></script>
      <!-- /AngularJS-ngMaterial-->
  
      <script type='text/javascript'>
          angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI - the `flex` tag refers to Apache Flex questions, not CSS flex layout questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the console in the debug window you will see this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined`

So I'm assuming there is an issue with your imports.

I extracted you `angular.module` statement to an external app.js file (not needed, but just so there is no confusion) and also replaced the css with one from angulars website. Here is a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.2/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app='myApp' layout='column'>
  <md-toolbar>
    <h1>Angular Material - Starter</h1>
  </md-toolbar>

  <div layout='row'>
    <div flex>
      blag
    </div>
    <div flex>
      blah
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.2/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

The CDNs that I used are from: https://github.com/angular/material#cdn

Comment: thank you! I feel so silly it was just the cdn. It's odd I didnt see the angular exception anywhere in the console. Thank you for the help, it is working now :)

Comment: on second glance I just failed at the link tag. No rel + href == sad two days.

Comment: Haha we've all been there. Glad I could help!